# Does any one knows what does mean : ERROR No matching node is available in Juju

Tags: juju, maas

I want to say there is no stable version of the implementation of `juju` with maas. Kind of error without any wise log output.whatever...does any one know at least approximately what refers to this error? making the same installation from different tutorials so many times but the same? is that the last version is bugging of something?

Answer (score 2):

After a long number reinstallation from scratch, it seems that juju does not like caching so it s recommanded if you plan to destroy the env and start from scratch to clean your cache !!! 
if you get stuck just try it !!! hopefully will work for you :-)